# Move Borderless Form using Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 3 panels and they are dock top, left and in the middle like container.

So there is no space left for clicking main form because of panels fullfilled.

I want to move my form clicking on the top docked panel.

Below code works fine without using panel ( clicking main form under the panel )

```
 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x84:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if ((int)m.Result == 0x1)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)0x2;
                return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

I tried to make it using panel1_MouseDown but no luck.

Is there a way to implement it ?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
bool moving;
Point offset;
Point original;

void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    moving = true;
    panel1.Capture = true;
    offset = MousePosition;
    original = this.Location;
}

void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!moving)
        return;

    int x = original.X + MousePosition.X - offset.X;
    int y = original.Y + MousePosition.Y - offset.Y;

    this.Location = new Point(x, y);
}

void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    moving = false;
    panel1.Capture = false;
}
```

Comment: still same. No movement.

Comment: @S.Zunbag Hmm well I made a simple app with two panels called panel1 and panel2, docked as you described, and the above code works. Therefore there must be some other factor not described in the OP. What happens if you make a simple app with two panels and use the code above?

Comment: @MatthewWatson it works as written above, I tried the same code using picture box & table layout panel and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

try this it works for me . use this method on the master panel i mean the panel you want to move the form or go and watch this video i found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CN1Y8diE3Zg

```
int mouseX, mouseY;
        bool mouseM;

        private void panel7_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseM = false;
        }

        private void panel7_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseX = e.X;
            mouseY = e.Y;
            mouseM = true;
        }

        private void panel7_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseM)
            {
                SetDesktopLocation(MousePosition.X - mouseX, MousePosition.Y - mouseY);
            }
        }
```